Umbraco show/hide conditions for submit button doesn't work
The latest Umbraco versions have the functionality to show or hide submit buttons using conditions. But for my case it doesn't work. For other field I have fieldsets and while iterating over fieldsets I do this
var hideFieldWhenRendering = f.HasCondition && f.ConditionActionType == FieldConditionActionType.Show;

and add class on the div like this  @{ if (hideFieldWhenRendering) { <text> umbraco-forms-hidden </text> } }
But submit buttons is not a part of fieldset and I don't find a way to check attribute HasCondition for it.
My html for submit looks like this
<div class="umbraco-forms-navigation row-fluid">

    <div class="col-md-12">
        @if (Model.IsMultiPage)
        {
            if (!Model.IsFirstPage)
            {
                <input class="btn prev cancel"
                       type="submit"
                       value="@Model.PreviousCaption"
                       name="__prev"
                       formnovalidate
                       data-form-navigate="prev"
                       data-umb="prev-forms-form" />
            }

            if (!Model.IsLastPage)
            {
                <input type="submit"
                       class="btn next"
                       value="@Model.NextCaption"
                       name="__next"
                       data-form-navigate="next"
                       data-umb="next-forms-form" />
            }

            if (Model.IsLastPage)
            {
                <input type="submit"
                       class="btn primary"
                       value="@Model.SubmitCaption"
                       name="__next"
                       data-form-navigate="next"
                       data-umb="submit-forms-form" />
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <div class='input -right submit-button'>
                <input type='submit' name="submitbtn" class='button -cta' id='submit' value='@Model.SubmitCaption'>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>

